# Any number starting with a 0 is recognized as a phone number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, mobile

During testing we noticed that on mobile devices, any number that is displayed starting with a 0 is recognized as a phone number. How can I keep this from happening?

We have policy number that are listed out in the header. I need them to remain unclickable and white in color instead of becoming a link for mobile users.

There seem to be lots of options for turning phone number recognition off for all pages and all links, but we do actually have phone numbers on the site and need the mobile phone recognition to remain working. I just need to ability to turn it off for this one section of the site - the header.

Any suggestions?

> Edit

Does anyone know how to set a format for numbers I **want** to recognize as phone numbers? That way I wouldn't worry about having to setup this number directly.

*For example: I only want number that follow this format to be recognized on mobile devices as a phone number* - 888.888.8888

Answer (score 2):

To disable the click give :

`pointer-events: none;`

To disable the styles:

`text-decoration:none; color:#fff;`

Something like this:

```
.selector { 
      pointer-events: none; 
      text-decoration:none; 
      color:inherit; 
}
```

Comment: This is actually not working. Normally, yes, with a link this would work. But the number I am referring to isn't a link, but on a phone (specifically an iphone 5/6) it still shows up as a link. This is my issue.

I added these styles to it and it continues to show up blue, underlined and clickable.